# Overleaf's beamer doesn't show table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

This is my code:

```
\begin{frame}{Overview} 
\tableofcontents
Here should be the table of contents, but it doesn't appear.
\end{frame}
section[Section]{Problem Setup}
\begin{frame}{Problem Setup}
\end{frame}
\section[Section]{Theory}
\begin{frame}{Some Theory}
\end{frame}
...
```

And so on up to 5 sections. The result is this:
[image: Empty TOC]
All the numbers are clickable, it seems like the text is just transparent.
I also have some theme modifications:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  {\color{HSEblue}\inserttocsectionnumber.}~\inserttocsection
}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=HSEblue}
```

The first command made the TOC visible at least as numbers (at first I didn't see even them), the second one seems to be not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @BambOo \documentclass{beamer}; \usepackage{HSE-theme/beamerthemeHSE-en}; \usepackage{multicol}; \graphicspath{{images/}}

Comment: Please, it is up to you to update your question. People here are willing to help, but you must show some effort too